# Want to know what are the taglibs available in spring-mvc

Tags: spring-mvc

I want to know what are the tag libs available in spring-mvc module.
I know there is taglib available for form

```
 "http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"
```

.
I just want to know any other tags available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the only tag library `spring-mvc` is provided with.

> [Spring-form tag libraries](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/spring-form-tld.html)

Apart from this `spring-security` provides security tag library.

> [Spring-security tag libraries](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/taglibs.html)